# In canasta, What is the top card of the discard pile?

Tags: canasta

This is very similar to existing questions, but resulted in heated debate. Here's the situation: first player discards a seven. Second player discards a wild card. Question: Is the top card a seven or wild? Third player has already gone down, has two sevens in hand and wants to pickup the discard with the wild card visibily on top. Is that a legal play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top card of the discard pile is always the most recently discarded card; the card physically on top of the rest. The fact that it is a wild card in this case doesn't change anything. Discarding a wild, like discarding a black three, is a way to ensure that the discard pile cannot be taken no matter what this turn.

From [the rules](https://www.pagat.com/rummy/canasta.html):

> Note that you can never take the discard pile if its top card is a wild card or a black three.

The rules do not really define "top" here, but it is using the common English language meaning, "the highest or uppermost point". If the newly discarded wild card were not considered the "top" card, then the quoted rule would make no sense, as there would never be a way to have a wild card be the top card of the discard pile.

Comment: I saw that but it doesn't actually state the wild card becomes the top card, it only says you must have two of the top card in your hand, which caused the debate as to whether the wild is actually transparent and not the top, but the seven under it. Is there somewhere it explicitly states the wild card and black three must stop the next player from taking the discard?

Comment: If having a wild card on top of a seven meant that the seven were the top card, then it would never be possible to have a wild card as the top card. There's not really a more specific rule than this; the rules are simply using the term "top" the way it is used in normal English. The card that is "on top" is the "topmost card". There can never be anything on top of the top card, because if something else were on top, it would be the top.

Comment: That was the assertion, thanks for clearing it up:)

Comment: @ForgetIwaseverhere Added.